# Issues in MVC 2 Routing controller Index Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I have Created a new Controller called **Consultants**. Then I create action method Index()..

I gave *route* like the following,

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
            "consultants",
            "consultants/index",
            new { controller = "Consultants", action = "Index" }
            );
```

In view, *ActionLink* method is,

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Consultant Home", "Index", "Consultants", null, new { title = "Back home" })%>
```

But it is not routing. It is showing `Resource cannot be find`

Please correct my issues...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've created a custom `RouteCollectionExtensions` called `MapRouteLowercase` (or at least I'm not familiar with it).  I'd test that to make sure it's working as you expect by changing your route to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "consultants",
    "consultants/index",
    new { controller = "Consultants", action = "Index" }
);
```

Otherwise, you may have another route map causing issues, so make sure that route config is at the very top of your routing.  Order plays an important role in how the route engine determines the correct url when searching for patterns.  So order from specific to general.

For example, if you did something like this, it would cause issues with your current route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "dateRoute",
    "consultants/{date}",
    new { controller = "Consultants", action = "Dates", date = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```